Low quality map with RTAB-Map
I'm trying to create a map via differential drive robot with RGBD camera Intel RealSense D435i and wheel odometry using RTAB-Map. The map is low quality (right picture). Also, I have a map which created using slam-toolbox and RPLidar A1 (left pictures). What can be wrong with first approach?

Several reasons can cause this problem according to my experience:

Your robot speed while mapping is high but the rate of image transfer or processing time is low due to your system config.
Your camera is not calibrated.
Odom topic or image topic is being published at low rate.
Your environment is featureless.
you have set the Kp/MaxFeatures parameter to a high rate in rtabmap configuration.

These are the things that pops into my mind for now but there might be other reasons too.

Thank you! I'll try to calibrate camera and change Kp/MaxFeatures.

Setting parameter Kp/MaxFeatures improved the quality of maps, but not enough. Also, I've found that map is building fine when robot is moving forward, but when robot is rotating, quality is terrible. My odom topic rate from turtlebot2 is 30 hz, and framerate from RealSenseD435i is 15 fps. I know that RealSense has On-Chip Self-Calibration feature. Do I still have to calibrate it?

No I dont think you need furthur calibration. If your environment is full of features, then maybe your odometry data has high covariance and the noise is too high, for this case you can try using the visual odometry of rtabmap itself. If thats not the problem try changing some rtabmap parameters according to your environment listed here: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/blob/master/corelib/include/rtabmap/core/Parameters.h like KP/MaxDepth and Grid/RayTracing. Thats all I can suggest for now.

With visual odometry works fine. Thank you!
